# Get substrings from string using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, split

I am trying to get sub-strings from a large one using RegEx. 
The sub-strings' format is as following:

- Starts with number 00-99 followed by an equals sign =.
- May contain at least one character. Any character.
- Ends with underscore '_'.

**Example sub-strings:**

```
01=#010.0000#001.0000#+10.0#AA_
02=#020.0000#002.0000#+20.0#BB_
```

**Example full string:**

```
01=#010.0000#001.0000#+10.0#AA_02=#020.0000#002.0000#+20.0#BB_
```

I tried this expression but it gets me the full string as a result.

```
^\d{2}=.+_$
```

I'm missing something. Any help?

Comment: If you want parts of a string then you first need to drop the anchors `^` and `$` as that will always match the entire string or will not match at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
\d{2}=.*?_(?=\d{2}=|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/te1G6I/1)

You may also require no digits before the match with a `(?<!\d)` negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\d)\d{2}=.*?_(?=\d{2}=|$)
```

The `\d{2}=.*?_(?=\d{2}=|$)` pattern matches 2 digits, `=`, and then any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the first `_` that has two digits and `=` after it or is at the end of the string.

Comment: Note that you may probably want to make your pattern more verbose if there are more specific requirements. See `\d{2}=(?:#[-+]?\d+\.\d+(?:_[-+]?\d+\.\d+)*)+_[a-zA-Z]{2}_` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/te1G6I/2).